# Calculate Expected Value of $MSR$?

Tags: self-study

The proof asks us to show that $E(MSR) = \sigma^2 + \beta_1^2 S_{xx}$

I tried expanding out to see this and I get:

$E(MSR) = E(SSR) = E(\hat{\beta_1} * S_{xy}) = E(\frac{S_{xy}}{S_{xx}} * S_{xy})$

I believe I can take the $S_{xx}$ out of the expectation but I don't know what to do with the remaining $S_{xy}$.

My professor may have skipped a step or two but he showed the following:

$E(SSR) = S_{xx}E(\hat{\beta_1^2})$
How did this result come about?

Edit: Unless... perhaps he multiplied by $\frac{S_{xx}}{S_{xx}}$

This leaves $S_{xx}E(\frac{S_{xy}^2}{S_{xx}^2}) = E(\hat{\beta_1}^2)$

Then using properties of expectation we can have

$S_{xx}[Var(\hat{\beta_1}) + E(\hat{\beta_1}^2)]$

And I already know $var(\hat{\beta_1}) = \frac{\sigma^2}{S_{xx}}$

Sorry for the question. If I may leave it, perhaps it will help a student in the future?

Comment: Please take your solution to the problem and provide it as an answer. It's OK to answer your own question on this site, and even more helpful to future visitors than having the solution stay within the question itself.

Answer (score 1):

Multiply by $\frac{S_{xx}}{S_{xx}}$

This leaves $S_{xx}E(\frac{S_{xy}^2}{S_{xx}^2}) = E(\hat{\beta_1}^2)$

Then using properties of expectation we can have

$S_{xx}[Var(\hat{\beta_1}) + E(\hat{\beta_1})^2]$

And I already know $var(\hat{\beta_1}) = \frac{\sigma^2}{S_{xx}}$